# Why after 5 fays my transaction status is STILL PENDING?I choose the lowest fee for BitCoins transaction that Atomic cryptowallet offers. Why after

Tags: transaction-fees

Can someone help me, maube just with an answer?
I wanted to transfer approx. 30€ of 0.00068911 BITCOINS.
And in ATOMIC CRYPTOWALLET you can chose whatever fee for speednof transaction you want, so I choose the lowest to get the most € out of my BTC after exchanging through exchane platform that send € to my SKRILL ACCOUNT.
I SENT BTC TO EXCHANGER AND THE TO SKRILL ACCOUNT ON 31st JANUARY 2024 IN THE MORNIN AND TODAY IS 4th FEBRUARY 2024 IN THE EVENING AND STATUS OF MY TRANSACTION IS STILL PENDING. ARE MY FUNDS LOST OR I WILL HAVE TO WAIT FOR WEEKS OR MONTHS FOR FUNDS TO FINALY GET TO MY SKRILL ACCOUNT OR BACK TO MY ATOMIC CRYPTOWALLET?
Here is the HASH of my transaction and I look at blockchain and there are transactions from my address to the exchang platform address, but no funds yet. Maybe can anyone look deeper in my hash and tell me more about my transaction, my HASH ADDRESS: https://bitcoin.atomicwallet.io/tx/b6a37f8459f0e76f8fb5fb7f63c51048dae65b7b847f3c7ce63dcb27746d94f4

AND JUST MY HASH: b6a37f8459f0e76f8fb5fb7f63c51048dae65b7b847f3c7ce63dcb27746d94f4

PLEASE SOMEONE HELP ME, IF THERE IS SOME SOLUTION TO GET MY FUNDS FASTER BACK ORBTO MY SKRILL.

OR JUST PLEASE ANSWE MY QUESTION.

THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

PETER